# AssertJ casting an extracted field to a Map

Tags: java, assertj

I have a `Message` object with `MessageHeaders` field. The `MessageHeaders` class implements a `Map<String, Object>`. I want to assert that I have specific headers set. I'm having trouble getting the `MapAssert` methods to come up.

Here's what I want to accomplish:

```
assertThat(actual)
  .extracting(Message::getHeaders) // This returns AbstractObjectAssert though
  .containsKeys("some key");  // Not available
```

Here's the `Message` and `MessageHeaders` class to be clear:

```
public class Message {
  private MessageHeaders headers;
  // getter
}


public class MessageHeaders implements Map<String, Object>, Serializable {
  // methods
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In order to use `MapAssert` you need to extract directly the `MessageHeaders` field and cast the extraction with `asInstanceOf` :

```
assertThat(actual)
.extracting("headers")
.asInstanceOf(InstanceOfAssertFactories.MAP)
.containsKey("some key");
```

Comment: `asInstanceOf()` was introduced in `AssertJ Core 3.13.0 Release`. I will have to update.

Comment: It changed to isInstanceOf()

Answer (score 7):

AssertJ Core 3.14.0 provides a new [`extracting()`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.assertj/assertj-core/3.14.0/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractObjectAssert.html#extracting(java.util.function.Function,org.assertj.core.api.InstanceOfAssertFactory)) to support direct casting, so you can write:

```
assertThat(actual)
  .extracting(Message::getHeaders, as(InstanceOfAssertFactories.MAP))
  .containsKey("some key");
```

Note that [`as()`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.assertj/assertj-core/3.14.0/org/assertj/core/api/Assertions.html#as(org.assertj.core.api.InstanceOfAssertFactory)) is an optional syntax sugar to improve readability.

Answer (score 0):

The solution / workaround I came up with was to assert the map itself instead of using extracting.

```
assertThat(actual.getHeaders())
  .containsKey("some key");
```